How to Generate a Single Report for Parallel Jobs Using Matrix in GitLab CI?
I'm using the parallel: matrix feature in GitLab CI to run tests in parallel for different test suites. My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

**yaml
Copy code
test:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - saas-linux-large-amd64
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - VAR: "@WebSuite1"
      - VAR: "@WebSuite2"
  script:
    - mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="$VAR"
  after_script:
    - |
      curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{
        "text": "Selenium Test Report: 'https://shaguf.gitlab.io/-/bites/acceptance-tests/-/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/target/cucumber.html'"
      }' $SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target/cucumber.html
    expire_in: 1 day**

This setup runs the tests in parallel for the @WebSuite1 and @WebSuite2 tags, and it works fine. However, the issue I'm facing is that each parallel job generates its own test report and sends it to Slack separately.
My Question:
Is there a way to aggregate the reports from both parallel jobs into a single report and send that as a single notification to Slack, instead of having separate reports for each suite?
Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
My Question:
Is there a way to aggregate the reports from both parallel jobs into a single report and send that as a single notification to Slack, instead of having separate reports for each suite?
Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

The only way I see would be to remove the upload from the parallel jobs, create a new job that takes both reports when the parallel jobs are done, merges them and uploads one report to slack. There is no automatic way to do this as far as I know

The solution I used when faced with this problem was to utilize a report aggregator, and I chose Allure Report.     I create the post on how to overcome this problem in this post        https://www.linkedin.com/posts/mohamed8ahmed_how-to-overcome-separated-reports-when-running-activity-7233193413066579968-xRgs?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop
